# Direct audio to bluetooth headset only if answered on headset buttons

Tags: bluetooth, calls, bluetooth-audio, headset, headset-controls

Is it possible to have the call audio redirected to the bluetooth headset only if the call is answered by using the buttons on the bluetooth headset.

That means that if I have lunch in the cafeteria located directly above my office the sound would not default to the headset at my desk, but in stead to the internal speaker of my phone - if answered by using the on screen button on the phone.

I know I can change the output by using the on screen buttons after answering the call - but were hoping to make an automatic selection based on the way the call is answered (button on headset / on screen button on the phone).

Third party apps or Tasker (or similar) script is an OK way to accomplish the task if needed.

Thanks in advance for all help given.

(Using an S7 Edge at the office - but are (firstly) looking for a generic answer.)

Comment: You can try [SoundAbout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.woodslink.android.wiredheadphoneroutingfix)

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The app seem to be able to direct the different types of audio to where you would like - but not direct audio _based on how the call is answered_.
So - sadly it does not solve my needs.